# Creating a Parent Node for XML document in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

My Code:

```
// Read in Xml-file 
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("C:/Web.config");

XmlNode d = doc.SelectSingleNode("/configuration");
XmlNode MYNODE = doc.CreateNode("element", "connectionStrings", "");

//newParent.(childNode);
d.AppendChild(MYNODE);

//Saving the document
doc.Save("C:/Web.config");
```

MyOutput in my Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings />
```

The output that i actually want in my Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>

</connectionStrings>
```

What must i change in my code to get the correct output?
Also, what must I do if i want my tags to appear just above another tag...Say my --SharePoint-- Tag.

Regards
Etienne

Comment: Re your question; something like: sharePoint.InsertAfter(MYNODE);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both of them are well formed xml formats.

but, if you add new childs to your your appended child node, you'll get what you want. For example just add an space into the connectionstrings node :

```
XmlNode MYNODE = doc.CreateNode("element", "connectionStrings", "");
MYNODE.InnerText = " ";
```

this will have no effect in actual use of connection strings elements.. but the output will be as you want.

Answer (score 2):

The output is correct. Since you do not have any child elements within the `connectionStrings` tag, it renders as an empty tag.

`<connectionStrings />` means the same thing as `<connectionStrings></connectionStrings>`.

If you want to insert a tag before a particular node, use the `InsertBefore` method:

```
XmlNode sharePoint = doc.SelectSingleNode("SharePoint");
XmlNode MYNODE = doc.CreateNode("element", "connectionStrings", "");

doc.InsertBefore(MYNODE, sharePoint);
```

Comment: Using the doc.InsertBefore(MYNODE, sharePoint); does  not work?

Answer (score 1):

Both the `<ConnectionStrings>` seems same. There is no difference in `<connectionStrings />` and `<connectionStrings></connectionStrings>.`

You can use `AppendChild()` or `InsertBefore()` or `InsertAfter()` methods to position your nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps add some white-space text into the element?

```
MYNODE.InnerText = " ";
```

Or some other content - maybe a comment? Without some content, the two forms are pretty-much identical.

Re the "tag" question - that depends what you mean... but `XmlNode` has `InsertBefore` and `InsertAfter` - just find the node you want it to be adjacent to and use one of those.

Comment: Thanks for the reply....how would i use the InsertBefore in my code....i tried a few things but keep getting an error.

Comment: try sharePoint.InsertAfter(MYNODE);

Comment: Nope, error say: "No overload for method InsertBefore takes '1' arfument

Comment: Answer : XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
         root.InsertAfter(connNODE, root.FirstChild);

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
root.InsertAfter(connNODE, root.FirstChild);
```

This is what i needed to do in onder to place my node in the correct spot.
Thanks everyone for your help!
Etienne

Answer (score 0):

Sorry its late but cannot hold myself to reply this post:

```
XmlNode xNode = xDoc.CreateNode("element", "FundDetails", ""); // Parent node to insert
xDoc.InsertBefore(xNode, xDoc.ParentNode); // inserting parent node to existing XML document
```

Answer (score 0):

> this code help parent node more data that get from database.

```
 XmlNode dataNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "connectionstrings", null);
                 root.PrependChild(dataNode);
                for (int i = 1; i < root.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
                {
                    dataNode.AppendChild(root.ChildNodes[i]);
                    i--;
                }
```

if you add new childs to your your appended child node, you'll get what you want. For example just add NULL into the connectionstrings node .